# forEach() inside filter()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following method:

```
getDeviceErrors(error) {
this.devices = this.data.segment.data.devices.filter((device) => {
          device[this.data.label].error.forEach((errorObj) => {
            if (errorObj.id === error.id) {
              console.log(true);
              return true;
            }
        });
      });
}
```

Although `true` is outputted to the console, `this.devices` is still empty.

Any idea why?

Comment: your `forEach` callback returns true but the `filter` callback doesnt...

Answer (score 7):

Your `filter` function does not actually return anything. To fix this, you could use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) as follows:

```
getDeviceErrors(error) {
    this.devices = this.data.segment.data.devices.filter((device) => {
        return device[this.data.label].error.some((errorObj) => {
            return errorObj.id === error.id;
        });
    });
}
```

And by the way: I would expect a function called `getDeviceErrors` to return something and not just change the state.